# Preserving small amounts of milk

Tags: food-preservation, milk

My husband and I do not drink milk during the week, and rarely use it for cooking. However, on weekends when I am home I like to make coffee and have it with milk. The problem is it is very expensive to purchase even the smallest container of 2% milk at the store only to have it go bad before I've gotten more than a quarter of the way through it.

Is there a way I can preserve a quart of milk for my coffee, without it going bad? Is freezing an option? I am not a fan of milk alternatives, or the little creamer things that are shelf stable.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8659/can-i-freeze-milk?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Freezing is most definitely one of the best options.

If you are only going to use a little at a time, then it would be a good idea to divide the quart into smaller portions so that you do not have to defrost the whole amount. You can use an ice-tray and take out just as many cubes as you need.

Comment: +1 Great idea with the ice tray. People don't know how many hacks there are to the tray. When you're done, take the cubes out, put them in a bag and leave in the freezer. I use the same idea for wine. Love it, but don't drink a lot, so I freeze the leftovers into cubes to use while cooking.

Comment: Good point about bagging the cubes! I do exactly the same with leftover wine and stock too. Bagging the cubes also helps to prevent the cubes from freeze drying and shrinking, and it frees up the tray to cube other things.

Comment: My ice cube tray is used for anything that's liquid I wish to save except for actual ice :) as I get brain-freeze even drinking something at ordinary fridge temperatures. All is bagged too. My favourite is juicing lemons & freezing them in the trays. Processed bottle lemon juice tastes foul! When I want to add lemon to tisanes, I pop a cube or two in. It's handy for lemon juice needed in cooking (not baking as I add larger quanities). I grate the rind before juicing & freeze it too. I can buy lemons year round but usually they're dry so when I find heavy lemons (therefore juicy), I buy a lot.

Comment: @Jude, share your taste on bottled "lemon juice"! I too freeze citrus rind/zest, but on its own and always away from juice as acidity and limonene in the zest is readily hydrolysed at low pH. Even things barely a liquid go into my ice tray as well!